# How can problems with shafts lead to premature cv boot failure?

Tags: cv-joint, cv-boot

I previously asked a question about why cv boots can fail and reasons given were cheap quality boots, improper installation and problems with shafts.

Regarding problems with shafts, what exactly might be wrong with them that they would cause a cv boot to fail prematurely?

I do remember that before I did these boot repairs, the torn boots had lead to knocking sounds(dried grease) coming from under the car for the most part of one year though I didn’t drive much.  After the repair the knocking sounds had gone.

Thanks.

Comment: Who has told you that shaft problems can lead to boot failure? Or are you asking if it can?

Comment: In my experience you have this backwards.  Boot failures quickly lead to CV joint failures since it allows water and dirt to enter the joint and cause damage.  It's almost always wise to rebuild the CV joint when replacing the boot or replace the entire shaft.  Now a CV joint that is somehow damaged may damage the boot through excess movement, sharp edges protruding from the assembly.

Comment: @GdD it was jw20.  But seems he is saying already damaged boots can lead to it.